# Anyone attempted to perform automated tasks through the PCOMM or x3270 using Perl?

Tags: perl, automation, mainframe, zos

Anyone attempted to  perform automated tasks through the PCOMM or x3270 using Perl?  I am doing some operations on Mainframe through PCOMM and x3270. Since some tasks include many repeatable operations, I am trying to find an easy way to automate these tasks on Mainframe.

BTW, Perl is my favorite language, so just mentioned Perl here.

Comment: your question seems vague to me

Comment: @Doboy: In short, I'd like to use Perl to do some operations, such as IPL, submit jobs, check for dumps and shutdown machine.

Comment: `crontabs` that run your `perl` scripts may be what you are looking for

Comment: @Doboy: crontabs could help me do parts of work. However, some operations must be completed through 3270 terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do some research on QUOTE SITE FILETYPE=JES.  This allows you to FTP batch jobs straight into the JES Spool.  I do this dozens of times a day (maybe hundreds) to get my PC to accomplish tasks on the mainframe.  If it can be done in batch, then this is a great way to do it.  And of course, Perl is an excellent way to create and manipulate the JCL before it's submitted.

Another thing to look into, if you Telnet to the mainframe, it opens a TSO command dialog (just like option 6 in TSO).  There are many things you can do there too.  Of course, if you're doing IPLs and the like, you already know this.

My trouble is that I am not a systems programmer so I cannot control the settings of the mainframe.  There are many settings that my company's systems guys are too lazy to look into, so they just shut them down out of hand.  I discovered the Telnet thing about a year ago, which I was using to see if a job had finished (that's the hard part of this... knowing when the job is done).  Next thing I know, the Telnet access had been disabled.

I have tons of things that allow me to do things on the mainframe via Perl.  Hit me up and I'd love to share them with you.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't read your reply until now. I also like Perl and Mainframe. Your sharing will be truly appreciated. May I have your email address?

Comment: MSwanberg -at- mikeswanberg.com.  Let me know what sort of stuff you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

I am not mainframe guy, but check this out

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=611038

"I automate 3270 applications from Perl by using the IBM Personal Communications 3270 terminal emulator on Win32 via Win32::OLE. It is very well documented and it works very good."

This with example code: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=674214

Using IPC to drive the session:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-do-i-use-s3270-x3270-for-scripting-767067/

I hope this help.

regards,

Comment: Thanks. I am trying out methods from these pages.

Comment: Automating tasks through the PCOMM API, of course, is not automating tasks "on the mainframe". Though it may solve your problem, it is misleading given the question. You should consider editing your question... To run Perl on z/OS, you need the IBM Ported Tools, a free set of tools that *run on z/OS*: http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/os/zos/features/unix/ported/perl/index.html

Comment: @rafraf: Thanks for your suggestion. Basically, my question is related to 3270 terminal(PCOMM or x3270). Question is updated right now.